# Both shift keys switching layout works only in a certain press order

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

In Ubuntu 20.04, I used gnome-tweaks to set layout switching to both Shift keys. However, it works only if Lshift was pressed before Rshift. Pressing Rshift, then pressing Lshift, then releasing both does not switch the layout.

I used the same configuration in Ubuntu 16.04, and the layout was switched regardless of the order in which I pressed shifts. Can this behaviour be reached in 20.04 as well?